# A structure for a text messages dictionary with system notifications/errors

Tags: hash-map

I would like to arrange a system messages dictionary for an application in JavaScript.

As an initial intention, I thought something about the following structure:

```js
export const SYS_MESSAGES = Object.freeze({

    fileSizeExceeded: {
        code: "FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED",
        text: "The file size exceeds allowed limit"
    }

});
```

But then I realized, the structure could be even more simple:

```js
export const SYS_MESSAGES = Object.freeze({

    FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED: "The file size exceeds allowed limit"

});
```

Which option of two structures is a preferred-one from maintenance/style perspective?

Answer (score 1):

I consider that the second option is better for the following:

- The first option is more verbose than the second, and it is in a way that there is no additional information which allow other developers or even you to obtain meaningful information.
- The second option has a constant style name which represents what you are trying to tell us, "hey, this is a constant and its value is ..." and so, it clearly reflects a shorter and descriptive code style.
- Having less properties (in your objects) implies less space, and less space computed implies less execution time. (even if it is very small).
- Less content helps you to debug faster.

Well, I hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, I also considered the second option, but then I realized that with a such structure it will be more difficult to get a code of a message. E.g. `SYS_MESSAGES.FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED` returns always a text message ("The file size exceeds allowed limit"), but if I want to get the message code itself (`FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED`), then I'll have to play with `Object.keys()` and rely on a permanent order of messages in the dictionary, which can be changed at any time day and will require adjusting the entire code base. That's why the option #1 is better, although it's more verbose.